# How does the game prioritize hearts?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

If I have white hearts, soul hearts, and normal hearts, in what order will they be taken when I am damaged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal priority excluding the blood machine is soul hearts, then white hearts, then regular hearts.

If you use the blood machine at more than half a regular heart, the priority becomes white hearts, then regular hearts, then soul hearts. At half a heart, it will consume white hearts, then soul hearts, then your last half a heart (killing you). This means if you have a white heart, it will be consumed *first* on a blood machine - watch out!

Comment: I was killed by blood donation despite soul hearts - it seems having half a regular heart left in Necropolis where blood donation requires a full heart is a bad idea...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the source of damage.

Generally, from monster hits, spikes and others, the order is soul -> white -> normal.

The blood donation machines are an exception because they will always drain your white hearts first then your normal hearts, until you have half a hart remaining, THEN drain your soul hearts

Comment: Blood machines actually take the white heart first, always.

Comment: @IanPugsley thanks for the correction, I modified the answer